# Tensorflow _ Symbol Zeros is already exposed as ()

Tags: python, tensorflow, import

I'm trying to import tensorflow with this code

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

and this error occurs
Tensorflow _ Symbol Zeros is already exposed as ()

I've tried to remove the import think that tensorflow is imported by default but the error persists

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What version of tensorflow do you have?  What version of Python?

Comment: Hello, have you resolved the issue? I'm encountering the same problem and haven't been able to find a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there might be an issue with the installation of TensorFlow. The error message you provided, "Tensorflow _ Symbol Zeros is already exposed as ()", suggests a problem with symbol names or conflicts during the import.  For more detailed information and additional options, you can refer to the official TensorFlow installation guide:[Link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip)

If you encounter any issues during the installation, make sure to check for updates on the TensorFlow GitHub repository or seek help from the TensorFlow community.

Comment: Thanks , i've tried to re-install tensorflow , and it worked for me